# The way to update CoreDate entity attribute according to the Section index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I am new in IOS developing, and try to make my first app(Something like workout tracker when u can choose the workout program or create the  custom one).
As I use CoreData I have the next dataModel - [DataModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eib3.png) .
I have a screen when the user can add more day's to the program, and add more exercise to particular day. 
This screen is presented by tableView where Days - are the sections, and exercises belonging to particular day  - are the rows.
tableView is populated with data by FetchedResultsController :

```
 fileprivate lazy var fetchedResultController: NSFetchedResultsController<Exercise> = {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Exercise> = Exercise.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "day.weekDayNum", ascending: true)
    let sortDesctiptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key:"countingNumber", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "day.programm = %@", self.selectedProgramm)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor, sortDesctiptor2]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath:  #keyPath(Exercise.day.weekDayNum), cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

In order to add new exercise to the day(section)I have a custom Section headers with label and "Add Exercise" button for adding the exercise to the particular section(Day).
For doing this i  need the way to identify the section index on which the user have tapped. Here what i have done to provide this ability - 
1) as my section name is represented by Day's "weekDayNum" int16 attribute - i can assign this  num to the AddExercise button TAG in tableView's viewForHeaderInSection. ->

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    let button = UIButton()

    button.setTitle("Add Ex", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addExerciseToDay(sender: )), for: .touchUpInside)

    let label = UILabel()
    guard let sectionInfo = fetchedResultController.sections?[section] else { fatalError("Unexpected Section") }
    label.text = "Day:" + "\(sectionInfo.name)"
    button.tag = Int(sectionInfo.name)!

    view.addSubview(label)
    view.addSubview(button)
```

2) When the user press this button the segue is called

```
 func addExerciseToDay(sender: UIButton){
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddExerciseSegue", sender: sender)
    print("Bttn touched at day num \(sender.tag)")
}
```

} and then i find that day and pass it to the next VC with the list of all exercises to choose

```
 if segue.identifier == "AddExerciseSegue"{
        if let sender = sender as? UIButton?{
            let weekDayNum = sender?.tag
            let day = Day.getDay(forProgram: selectedProgramm, withWeekDayNum: weekDayNum!)
            let allExercisesVC = segue.destination as! AllExercisesViewController
            allExercisesVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
            allExercisesVC.selectedDay = day
        }
```

where i just assign selected exercise to that day.
It works fine for me, but the most interesting part begins when i try to add the new day to the program.
For this i have the UITabBarButton which works almost the same as previous AddExercise bttn (because for the section(day) to be shown  i need add at least one exercise to that NEW day(section)).
Here the code ->

`@IBAction func addDayButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "AddExerciseSegue", sender: sender)
    }`

and

```
  if let _ = sender as? UIBarButtonItem?{
            print("\(String(describing: selectedProgramm.days?.allObjects.count))")
            let day = Day(withWeekDayNum: Int16((selectedProgramm.days!.allObjects.count + 1)))
            selectedProgramm?.addToDays(day)
            let allExercisesVC = segue.destination as! AllExercisesViewController
            allExercisesVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
            allExercisesVC.selectedDay = day

        }
```

Day(withWeekDayNum:..) - is just convenient init.And weekDayNum is calculated as count of all days in this programs + 1 in order to add it as the last day on the tableView. 
It works fine too, but only if u delete or add only last section (as a stack). But if , for example, i have 3 days , and i delete the 2nd one, and then try to add new day - its just add the exercise to the 3rd day, but dont create the 4th day with that exercise as it supposed.  I understand WHY this is happened - because after deleting my 2nd day - the count of ALL days in this program is 2. And the ex 3rd day is still have weekDayNum = 3. And as i said before "weekDayNum is calculated as count of all days in this programs + 1 in order to add it as the last day on the tableView." And thus 2 + 1 = 3..not 4. 
I need the way to update my weekDayNum day's attribute according to the "REAL SECTION NUMBER" As when u delete Second day - the third day becomes second - the next one - third, next one fourth..
Is that real? or my approach is totally wrong, and if it is - I'll be happy to hear another one. 
SORRY FOR THE MISTAKES, English is not my first language.
Thank you in advance!

//To the comment below -- here is FRC delegate methods , but it seems to me that i need a way to "manually" tell the FRC to update the **weekDayNum** attribute, as the section INDEX and weekDayNum attribute of DAY entity are the separate things.

```
extension FillUPProgrammViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}


func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
    default:
        break
    }
}


func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}



func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer:sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer:sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    default :
        break
    }
}
```

}

Comment: when using a FetchResultsController it should update itself, please can you show your FRC delegate methods

Comment: I have updated my post.